# How to disable CSS Animations once it has finished

Tags: html, css

I have this windows 10 Simulator animation that runs a gradient of blue and red. This animation transitions from left which starts with black, to right which has red, then transitions back left to black and that's when the animation ends. I am trying to find a way on how to pause/disable the animation after it has ran once (Left to right then back left)
To make room for my next css animation however I do not know how to execute this.

Is there a simple css attribute that makes animations only run once?

```
            <html>
    <head>
    <title>Windows 10 Simulator</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/
    css?family=Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|
    Raleway|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>


    <style onload>
    html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    background-color: #000;
    }

    .wrapper { 
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      left:0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(124deg,  #000000, #000000, #0095f0 ,#0095f0, #0095F0, #ff0000, #ff0000, #0095f0);
    background-size: 1800% 1800%;

    animation-iteration-count: 0;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: rainbow 30s ease infinite;
    }


    @keyframes rainbow { 
        0% {background-position:  0% 0%}
        10%{background-position: 100%% 15%}
        20%{background-position: 100% 30%}
        30%{background-position: 100% 45%}
        40%{background-position: 100% 60%}
        50%{background-position: 100% 85%}
        60%{background-position: 100% 90%}
        70%{background-position: 100% 100%}
        80%{background-position: 100% 90%}
        90%{background-position: 100% 85%}
        80%{background-position: 100% 45%}
        100%{background-position:100% 15%}
        }



      span {
      margin-top: 250px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      animation-name: flickerAnimation;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;   
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      }

      #message{
      font-size: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      animation-name: alertFade;
      animation-duration: 4s;

      opacity: 0;
      animation-iteration-count: 1000;
      margin-top: 620px;
      }

      span:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 1s;
      animation-duration: 5s;

      }

      span:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 7s;
      animation-duration: 7s;
      }

      span:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 15s;
      }

      span:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 22s;
      }


      @keyframes flickerAnimation{

      0% {opacity: 0;}
      50% {opacity: 1;}
      100% {opacity: .0;}

      }

      @keyframes alertFade{
      0% {opacity: .25}
      50% {opacity: .75}
      100% {opacity: .25}
      }



      </style>
      <div class="wrapper">



      <span>Hello! </span>
      <span>Please Wait While We Setup</span>
      <span>This Will Only Take a Few Seconds</span>
      <span>Just a second...</span>


      <div style="text-align: center;">
      <p id="message" align="center">Please Do Not Turn 
              Off Your Device.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .wrapper class, change the following animation property:

`animation: rainbow 30s ease infinite;`
to:
`animation: rainbow 30s ease 1;`

You've set the animation-iteration-count to 0 with `animation-iteration-count: 0;` and then asked it to play **infinitely** with the animation property below `rainbow 30s ease infinite;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also omit it altogether as the default is to play once.